# How to send specific line item data to third party script

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to send price, name and id of each item in the order, plus an extra static value to a single js variable formatted in this way,

items = eventID::price::name|eventID::price::name|eventID::price::name

I was trying to do it this way, but I'm getting an error on the last line which I mean to add a pipe if there is more than one product.

```
$line_items = $order->get_items();

//loop over line items
$wgItemCount = $order->get_item_count();

$wgItems = array();   
foreach ( $line_items as $item ) {
    $wgItem = array();
    $wgItem ['eventId'] = '777777';
    $wgItem ['eventId'] .= '::';
    $wgItem ['price'] = $order->get_line_total( $item, true, true );
    $wgItem ['price'] .= '::';
    $wgItem ['name'] = $item->get_name();
    if ($wgItemCount > 1) { //add divider if more than one item
        wgItem .= '|';
    } 
    
    $wgItems[] = $wgItem;
}
```

That hasn't worked so far, so I thought maybe I should create a custom object that contains the variables instead:

```
wgProduct = "77777", $order->get_line_total( $item, true, true ), $item->get_name();
```

and then call the items in a list later like

```
echo print ("|", wgProduct)
```

I had also tried using JSON to encode the data but the third party told me that is not going to work for their needs.

Edit: Code is now doing everything I need it to, but it's only pulling one item from the list instead of a string of all of them.

Here's what it looks like now based on the help I got here:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou','wg_tracking' );

function wg_tracking( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    $shipping_total =  $order->get_shipping_total();
    $order_total = $order->get_total();
    $currency = $order->get_currency();
    $coupons = $order->get_coupon_codes();
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $total_exc_shipping = $order_total - $shipping_total;
    $order_discount = $order->discount_total;
    
    foreach( $coupons as $coupon ){
        $coupon_post_object = get_page_by_title($coupon, OBJECT, 'shop_coupon');
        $coupon_id = $coupon_post_object->ID;

        $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_id);
    }
    
    $wgItems = array();   
    
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $line = '';
        $line .= '77777';
        $line.= '::' . $order->get_line_total( $item, true, true );
        $line .= '::' . $item->get_name();
        $line .= '::' . $item->get_id();
        }
    $wgItems[] = $line;
    $itemsList = implode('|', $wgItems);    
?>
<script>
     (function(w,e,b,g,a,i,n,s){w['ITCVROBJ']=a;w[a]=w[a]||function(){
        (w[a].q=w[a].q||[]).push(arguments)},w[a].l=1*new Date();i=e.createElement(b),
        n=e.getElementsByTagName(b)[0];i.async=1;i.src=g;n.parentNode.insertBefore(i,n)
    })(window,document,'script','https://analytics.webgains.io/cvr.min.js','ITCVRQ');
    ITCVRQ('set', 'trk.programId', 88888);
    ITCVRQ('set', 'cvr', {
        value: '<?php echo $total_exc_shipping ?>',
        currency: '<?php echo $currency ?>',
        language: 'de_DE',
        eventId: 77777,
        orderReference : '<?php echo $order_id ?>',
        comment: '',
        multiple: '',
        checksum: '',
        items:  '<?php echo $itemsList ?>',
        voucherId: '<?php if ( $order_discount > 0 ) echo $coupon->get_code(); ?>'
    });
    ITCVRQ('conversion');
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this all can be simplified to just use array's [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) method.
Below are what I would do in your situation:

```
$wgItems = array();
foreach ( $line_items as $item ) {
    $line = '';
    $line .= '777777';
    $line .= '::' . $order->get_line_total( $item, true, true );
    $line .= '::' . $item->get_name();
    
    $wgItems[] = $line;
}

$items = implode('|', $wgItems);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I see I was over-complicating it. I had considered using implode but I didn't think to simplify the items to objects instead of arrays in that way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is only pulling the last item on the list for some reason. Any clues?

Comment: check how you concatenate and the variable assignment